# Node.js "UserLogged" function returning "undefined". Why?

Tags: nodejs, javascript, functions

When I get to the end of the code below, it always returns "undefined" and I don't know why!

```
function UserLogged (session) {
  if (session === null) {
    var err = new Error('Not logged in');
    err.status = 400;
    return {user : null, err : err};
  }
  User.findById(session.userId)
  .exec(function (error, user) {
    if (error) {
      return {user : null, err : error};
    }
    else {
      if (user === null) {
        var err = new Error('Not authorized!');
        err.status = 400;
        return {user : null, err : err};
      }
      else {
        console.log("User found and ok!");
        return {user : user, err : null};
      }
    }
  });
}
```

It does log "User found and ok!" on the console, but still returns "undefined"

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to return something from inside a callback function. Javascript basically works asynchronously for i/o operations. The function declared inside the `.exec()` is the callback function here.

I found this link useful to understand asynchronous coding.
https://blog.risingstack.com/node-hero-async-programming-in-node-js/

You could change your code similar to this to make it work

```
function UserLogged (session, callback) {
  if (session === null) {
    var err = new Error('Not logged in');
    err.status = 400;
    return callback(err);
  }
  User.findById(session.userId)
  .exec(function (error, user) {
    if (error) {
      return callback(error);
    }
    else {
      if (user === null) {
        var err = new Error('Not authorized!');
        err.status = 400;
        return callback(err);
      } else {
        console.log("User found and ok!");
        callback(null, user);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

The callback argument should be a function similar to this

```
UserLogged(session, function(err, user) {
  console.log(err);
  console.log(user);
})
```

Passing "err" as the first argument for the callback function is a nodejs standard.

Hope this helped you :D